# How to remember all buffer settings without "hidden"?

Tags: hidden-buffers

When I close the last sub-window for a file, assuming that it has no
sub-windows opened in any other tab, is there a way to have Vim
remember all options (comments, textwidth, tabstop, shiftwidth,
formatoptions, colorcolumn, wrap, highlight, spell, foldenable, foldmethod, foldcolumn, etc.), as if
`hidden` was set?

I want Vim to use those options if I re-open the file, and I want this
to happen for *all* files.  I don't want to set `hidden` or
`bufhidden` because I want to be forced to write the file if I'm
closing the last sub-window.

**Afternote:** After much perusing of Vim Q&A's and documentation, online and local, I suspect that the solution may lie in using `hidden`, but also using `autocommand` with the `WinClosed` event and some VimScript online to check whether a buffer is opened elsewhere.  If not, then find a way to prompt the user to write the file.  This is a vague sketch of a possibility.  I will post back if I progress the idea.

Comment: If you are setting these options manually, consider making them automatic via `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` or with autocommands for specific files?

Comment: The thing is that I seeking this behaviour for *all* files, regardless of the extension.  Sometimes, (say) a *.txt buffer may have shiftwidth=3 and tabstop=3, other times they may be 4.  Same with (say) *.py.  Whether folders are enabled, the fold method, etc. is dynamic.  It may be one thing this hour, something else the next hour, depending on the file.  They're not necessarily common across files with the same extension.  Does your suggestion still apply in this case?

Answer (score 1):

That's "Window", not "sub-window".

Also, as long as the buffer is in the buffer list it will keep all its buffer-local options, including `comments`, `textwidth`, `tabstop`, `shiftwidth`, and `formatoptions`. This means that you can `:w` buffer `a`, switch to buffer `b`, then come back to buffer `a`, which will be just as you left it. Those options are gone, though, if you quit Vim.

Other options, like `colorcolumn`, `wrap`, `spell`, `foldenable`, `foldmethod`, or `foldcolumn` are window-local, which means that they are gone when you close the window. They have nothing to do with buffers so it doesn't make sense to tie them to a buffer.

And `highlight` is global anyway, so it is out of scope.

To me, it looks like you want something like `:help modeline`, but `:help :mkview` might give you more flexibility.